# Writing a query to include certain values but exclude others when looking for a latest time period

Tags: sql, syntax

I am trying to write a query that looks for a people that have a certain code with the latest period (year) but not if they have another code with that latest period(year).  I'll be explicit just so my example makes sense.

I want people who have the code A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 but not AG,AP,AQ.  There are people who have an A1 code for a period (like 2014) and an AG code for a the same period.  I'd like to exclude them. Not everyone has a code so the field value could be `NULL`.

Is there a way to express this in a different way (i.e. less characters) than the way I did?

```
SELECT 
    people.firstName
FROM 
    people
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM codes
    WHERE 
        codes.people_id = people.id
        AND period = (SELECT MAX(period) FROM codes codes2 WHERE codes2.people_id = codes.people_id)
        AND code LIKE 'A[1-5]'
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM codes
    WHERE 
        codes.people_id = people.id
        AND period = (
            SELECT MAX(period) 
            FROM codes codes2 
            WHERE codes2.people_id = codes.people_id
        )
         AND code LIKE 'A[GPQ]'
)
```

Schema is as follows:

**People**

- id (PK)
- firstName

**Codes**

- people_id (FK) many to one relation with People table
- code (e.g. "A1", "A2", "AG")
- period  (e.g. "2013", "2014")

Comment: Does your query give the correct result?

Comment: Could you provide the schema involve?

Comment: My query does give me the correct result, but I'm wondering if I could be writing it in a more efficient way.

Comment: You might get more answers if you include the database being used (e.g. MySQL, Oracle or Sql Server) and possibly a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some dummy data that people can test their queries on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways you could do that, I'm not an SQL expert but I can't see your query being too bad, if you want to try and reduce the number of sub-queries you could consider using the [`GROUP BY` clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php) along with a [`SUM`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php) [Aggregate function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) in a [`HAVING` clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php).

I started updating your code as follows:

```
SELECT 
    people.firstName
FROM 
    people
    LEFT JOIN codes AS a15 ON a15.people_id = people.id AND a15.code LIKE 'A[1-5]'
    LEFT JOIN codes AS agpq ON agpq.people_id = people.id AND agpq.code LIKE 'A[GPQ]'
GROUP BY
    people.firstName
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN a15.code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) > 0
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN agpq.code IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

This however doesn't take into account anything to do with period specific requirements described. You could add the period to the `GROUP BY` clause or add it to a `WHERE` or one of the `JOIN` constraints but I'm not quite sure from your description exactly what you're after (I don't believe this is through any fault of your own, I just can't personally align the code provided to the description).

I would also like to point out that the `SUM` functions above will not give an accurate count of the number of matching codes. This is because if both `A[GPQ]` and `A[1_5]` return at least one row, the number returned by each constraint will be multiplied by the number returned for the other, it can however be used to determine if there are "any" returned items as if the criteria is matched it will have a `SUM(...) > 0`

I'm sure a more experienced SQL Developer / DBA will be able to poke many holes in my proposed query but it might give them or someone else something to work from and hopefully gives you ideas for alternatives to using sub-queries.